# Angularjs or JQuery ? Which one will compile first?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In my application I am using both.I am curious which one will compile first?

Comment: What does that even mean? jQuery is compiled?

Comment: Neither compile. Ever. If you're asking which one gets loaded first, the one you added to the DOM first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever the interpretor encounters first is executed first. The order matters, not the framework or its size. It is like first come first served.

Also, you shouldn't use "compile" word here as javascript is interpreted and not compiled.